# VBA to correctly loop through an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have read through a number of summaries of arrays but I am still lost and looking for much appreciated help.  I have successfully created a non-array macro that copies a row in my ws and places below that parent row three copies.  It does this for every row in the ws.

eg

```
From:

ColA     ColB
Tom      Tent
Barry    Stove

To:

ColA     ColB
Tom      Tent
Tom      Tent
Tom      Tent
Tom      Tent
Barry    Stove
Barry    Stove
Barry    Stove
Barry    Stove
```

There are > 4000 rows to loop through.  My code works fine but it is slow.  So I read that placing the ws into an array is better and then loop through the array.  Here is where I am lost with arrays; how do I execute this copy and paste x 3 when I bring the ws into an array?  I have written some code below but not sure how to execute this further.  Many thanks.

```
Sub LoadDataintoArray()

Dim StrArray As Variant
Dim TotalRows As Long



TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
StrArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(TotalRows, 1)).Value

MsgBox "Loaded " & UBound(StrArray) & " items!"

'HERE I NOW WISH TO COPY EACH ROW IN THE WS (EXCEPT HEADER) AND PASTE THREE COPIES OF THAT ROW IMMEDIATELY BELOW THE PARENT ROW

'CODE I USED NOT USNG AN ARRAY IS BELOW
'
'    lRow = 2
'    Do While (Cells(lRow, "B") <> "")
'
'        RepeatFactor = 4
'
'        Range(Cells(lRow, "A"), Cells(lRow, "G")).Copy
'
'        Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + RepeatFactor - 1, "G")).Select
'
'        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'
'           lRow = lRow + RepeatFactor - 1
'
'        lRow = lRow + 1
'    Loop
'

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading arrays is somewhat faster than reading cell values.  The real performance gain is writing the data back to the worksheet.

As always I recommend watching [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on Youtube.   This is the relevant video: [Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

```
Sub RepeatData()
    Dim Data As Variant, Data1 As Variant
    Dim x As Long, x1 As Long, x2 As Long, y As Long

    Data = Range("A2:G2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    ReDim Data1(1 To UBound(Data, 1) * 4, 1 To UBound(Data, 2))

    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For x1 = 1 To 4
            x2 = x2 + 1
            For y = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                Data1(x2, y) = Data(x, y)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    Range("A2:G2").Resize(UBound(Data1, 1)).Value = Data1

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing.  This added four additional rows where I need three; not sure where to amend the code just to add three.  Thanks.

Comment: Thomas, yes I did try it and it works.  As I need four rows I am just not there yet on reading the code and knowing how to modify it to get four rows.  I played with it by trial and error...more on the error side.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andes2016 sorry that I miss read your question and comment.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for modifying!  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    With Range("A2:G2", Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        Data = .Value
        For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            .Rows(4 * (x - 1) + 1).Resize(4) = Application.index(Data, x, 0)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

which exploits [this trick](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/) I knew from Thomas Inzina

Comment: Many thanks for sharing.  This works but gives three rows.  Can you please explain where to modify to give four rows?

Comment: I think I learned how to modify to give four rows: Rows(4 * (x - 1) + 1).Resize(4) = Application.index(Data, x, 0).  Correct?  Can you explain what is going on in this last?

Comment: You are welcome and correct: `Rows(4 * (x - 1) + 1).Resize(4) = Application.index(Data, x, 0)` will copy four times (I'll edit the answer). As for the explanation:  1) `.Rows(3 * (x - 1) + 1)`  references every third row of referenced range (`Range("A2:G2", Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))`: row 1, 4, 7 ... 2)`.Resize(3)` extends it to span three rows. 3) `Application.index(Data, x, 0)` takes `Data` array `x`th row and assigns it to the three rows range . Finally you may want to mark answer as accepted, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the Plug...lol.  +1 because I like the by far the easiest to read and modify.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, BTW did you ever succeed in having that _trick of the year_ really write more than one row (or column) out of an array in one shot?

Comment: No luck with slicing multiple rows or columns using `Index`.

Comment: Andes2016 you're welcome. @ThomasInzina then it should be downgraded to the "trick of the month"!

Comment: Thanks again but I just stumbled across it before you did.  I did come up with a neat trick to [Transpose Data using a For Each loop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JOjNsNiKm3WZndmF3HMOkhFF33X9w69qEOLxjMgRKRQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

This code will be more flexible should you decide to alter the number of repetitions, or the number of columns that you want to have repeat with each row.

```
Sub test1()

  'Set your input range to include all of the rows and all of the columns to repeat
  Dim StrArray As Variant
  StrArray = Range("A2:B5")

  Const numRepeats As Long = 4
  Const outputColumnStart As Long = 4

  Dim rowCounter As Long
  Dim colCounter As Long

  'Dimension a new array and populate it
  ReDim newArray(LBound(StrArray, 1) To UBound(StrArray, 1) * numRepeats, LBound(StrArray, 2) To UBound(StrArray, 2))

  For rowCounter = LBound(StrArray, 1) To UBound(StrArray, 1)
    Dim repeatCounter As Long
    For repeatCounter = 0 To numRepeats - 1
      For colCounter = LBound(StrArray, 2) To UBound(StrArray, 2)
        newArray(((rowCounter - 1) * numRepeats + 1) + repeatCounter, colCounter) = StrArray(rowCounter, colCounter)
      Next colCounter
    Next
  Next rowCounter

  'Write the values to the sheet in a single line.
  With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(UBound(newArray, 1), outputColumnStart + UBound(newArray, 2) - 1)).Value = newArray
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing and for the explanations in your code.